Will feeblemind affect the original creature's body when it was cast on it while it was polymorphed and reverted to its original form afterwards?
I tend to think that the original body should not be affected by the spell since casting polymorph on an already-feebleminded creature temporarily assumes the game statistics of the beast. Intelligence and Charisma are clearly part of the game statistics but the other effects also seem to be?
So far this question seems to only have been answered in the reverse.

is the polymorphed creature a valid target for feeblemind?

@Trish Why would it not be? The only requirements for the spell are "A creature that you can see within range".

Related: Which form(s) does the Shadow's Strength Drain attack affect when cast on a Wild Shaped, Shapechanged, Polymorphed or True Polymorphed character?

Yes, it will
Ongoing spell effects are not part of a creature's statistics, so they are not replaced when the creature is polymorphed, and not un-replaced when polymorph ends.
Feeblemind is a bit tricky, because it has a duration of Instantaneous, and normally the effects of instantaneous spells are permanent and non-magical, so normally it would only set the beast's Intelligence to 1 (whatever it was before), and when the beasts stats go away, that Intelligence of 1 also would.
However, feeblemind says:

At the end of every 30 days, the creature can repeat its saving throw against this spell. If it succeeds on its saving throw, the spell ends.

This effect is more specific than the general rule, and overrides it. Feeblemind creates an ongoing spell effect, and that effect will stick to the creature when polymorph goes away, until it makes its save. Since the main effect of feeblemind is

On a failed save, the creature's Intelligence and Charisma scores become 1. The creature can't cast spells, activate magic items, understand language, or communicate in any intelligible way. The creature can, however, identify its friends, follow them, and even protect them.

And since it is still the same creature that failed the save (just with different stats), this effect will continue to set its Intelligence to 1.

Why do you think the recovery mechanic is a more specific rule? I read it as Feeblemind being a form of "damage" with a unique recovery mechanic (the saving throw isn't against the actual magic of the spell anymore, since with an instantaneous effect, there is no magic remaining). I'm not saying you're wrong, but I'm not sure you're right, and if so, for the right reasons. Feeblemind being instantaneous is the real problem here, as it means it doesn't have an obvious answer in combining magical effects.

On my first point, Feeblemind is the same as any damage causing effect, it's just the hit points have existing rules for recovery, while shattered intellect/personality needs recover rules spelled out. Polymorph wearing off restores your original stats and hit points, and while I feel like an 8th level spell like Feeblemind shouldn't be foiled by use of a 4th level spell, I don't see an obvious way to read what Feeblemind does differently from any other form of ability or HP damage which gets undone by reverting.

@ShadowRanger I think it's more specific because one is s general rule that applies to all spells, while the other is mentioned for exactly the feeblemind spell. And a rule given for one individual spell is more specific than one for spells in general. At least, that is how I understand it.

I’m not sure this is ability “damage”. Yes it sets your ability to a fixed value while the effect is active, but, for example, I’d not think of a headband of intellect as "healing" or "damage" (depending on your prior Int) either.

I appreciate your help as always, Nobody!
